# NG2 Chart with Angular: Can't bind to 'colors' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas' in Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-charts

Template`<canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [type]="barChartType" [colors]="chartColors"></canvas>`
Code:

```
  public chartColors: Array<any> = [
{
  backgroundColor: ['#d13537', '#b000b5']
}
```

]
I am getting error:-
Can't bind to 'colors' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'.
I am using
"@angular/cdk": "^13.1.1",
"@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
"ng2-charts": "^3.0.8",
"chart.js": "^3.7.1",
and my working code with  "@angular/common": "^7.2.5" is at url
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-and-line-qkglqd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the [colors] parameter, use [data] and include a backgroundColor array inside of the dataSet. Like this:

HTML

```
<canvas baseChart
        [data]="barChartData"
        [labels]="barChartLabels"
        [type]="barChartType">
</canvas>
```

TS

```
import { ChartData, ChartType } from 'chart.js';

...

  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar'
  public barChartLabels: string[] = ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3'];
  public barChartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
    labels: this.barChartLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Title label",
        data: [5, 3, 1],
        backgroundColor: ["red", "green", "blue"],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["darkred", "darkgreen", "darkblue"],
      }
    ]
  };
```

It seems you're using the configuration of a different version. This method worked for me using Angular 12 and "ng2-charts": "^3.0.8". You can read the documentation for the current version here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

Answer (score 0):

have same issue with Angular 13.2.3 !

Aso, experienced that putting the canvas in

```
<ng-template>
```

does not cause the build error but the chart is not appearing.